# silverlight2 Message class missing CreateBufferedCopy method

Tags: soap, silverlight-2.0, message

I am trying to read a soap response twice and I got the error message already read ... There are some examples how to avoid this BUT ... they are using the **CreateBufferedCopy** method and **I cannot find** it on the silverlight2 Message object:

Microsoft has also this sentence in the silverlight doc :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.getreaderatbodycontents(VS.95).aspx
"If you want to access the body multiple times, use CreateBufferedCopy(Int32) to create a MessageBuffer instance."

Comment: Why do you want to read the response twice?  This is generally considered bad use, as the code that sends/receives data should be abstracted away, such that consumers just get the data... at that point, you have a reference to the data.

Comment: I am not talking about good or bad practices, I have a clear question about a missing method!

Comment: This isn't available in Silverlight 4 either, contrary to the Silverlight documentation.